# How to build an agenda buffer from specific files listed in org-agenda-files?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

`A` being the set of all the .org files I use for schedules, I restrained agenda searches to `A` like this :

```
(setq org-agenda-files (quote ("../file_1.org"
                               "../file_2.org"
                               ...
                               "../file_n.org"
                               )))
```

It is useful to be able to see all the tasks stored in these files in an agenda view. However, I would also like to be able to have an agenda view showing only the content of a specific subset of `A`. This specific subset being different according to the project I'm working on.

For example, let's say I would like to switch between `org-agenda-list` for `file_1.org` and `file_2.org` and `org-agenda-list` for `file_5.org`.

Comment: How about let-binding `org-agenda-files` when you call `org-agenda` or when you expressly call one of the three main functions, i.e., `org-agenda-list`, `org-tags-view` and/or `org-search-view`?  E.g., `(let ((org-agenda-files '("../file_1.org" "../file_2.org"))) ...)`

Comment: @lawlist thanks for your answer, but unfortunately my Emacs knowledge is not advanced enough to be able to understand it. How and where am I supposed to put `(let ((org-agenda-files '("../file_1.org" "../file_2.org"))) ...)`?

Comment: The question is a bit too general for me to be able to write up a global solution, but perhaps another forum participant can come up with one.  It might be helpful for you to state how it is that call a particular agenda command, and that way the answer can be specific to your needs and also tested to ensure that it works before someone posts an answer.

Comment: The example you took is relevant as the subset could be file 1 and 2. Or also only file 1. My only concern was, where/how to put the command you gave me.

Comment: There is more than one way to launch a function that ultimately will lead to the population of an agenda buffer; e.g., `M-x org-agenda-list`; `M-x org-search-view`; `M-x org-tags-view`; `M-x org-agenda`; some particular keyboard shortcut; etc.

Comment: To build the agenda buffer I do `C-c a a`. Which corresponds to `M-x org-agenda-week-view`

Comment: When you have time, go ahead and give this a try:  `(defun my-function (&optional iso-week) "Doc-string for this function." (interactive "P") (let ((org-agenda-files '("../file_1.org" "../file_2.org"))) (org-agenda-week-view iso-week)))`  Inasmuch as I use a highly modified *older* version of `org-mode`, I don't really have a way of testing this proposed function without setting everything up again from scratch.

Comment: When I run `(let ((org-agenda-files '("../file_1.org" "../file_2.org"))) (org-agenda-week-view iso-week))` with `M-:`,  I have the following error : `(void-function org-agenda-week-view)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the most idiomatic way to do this is to set `org-agenda-custom-commands` with an agenda let-binding `org-agenda-files`.  Something like:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("o" "crocefisso" agenda ""
         ((org-agenda-files
           '("../file_1.org" "../file_2.org"))))))
```

(Untested, since I don't have your setup here, but take a look at the variable's docstring and the manual and, if you are not familiar with the variable, you may want to use the customize interface to set it).

Comment: Marvelous! On top of that, it solves the issue of going back to `D` with `f` and `b`. Thanks!

Comment: @crocefisso Indeed, let-binding for the agenda is unusually tricky. Since an agenda can have multiple blocks, and each can have a different set of variables set, they are stored in the agenda buffer as text properties, everything else is actively cleared. That's why your attempt worked for the "first view" but not for subsequent ones.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [lawlist](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/2287/lawlist) suggestions I managed to find a solution. But first I had to learn how to deal with functions and key binding in Emacs Lisp (I hope my code is compliant with conventions).

**Note that this solution works even if `file_1.org`, `file_2.org` and `file_5.org` don't belong to `A`.**

So here is the code to put in the .emacs config file:

Code for file_1.org and file_2.org, key bound with `C-c n`

```
(defun file_1_and_2()
  "lauch org-agenda for file_1.org and file_2.org."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-agenda-files '("../file_1.org" "../file_2.org"))) (org-agenda))
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c n") 'file_1_and_2)
```

Code for file_5.org, key bound with `C-c s`.

```
(defun file_5()
  "lauch org-agenda for file_5.org."
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-agenda-files '("../file_5.org"))) (org-agenda))
  )
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c s") 'file_5)
```

The only drawback, is that when I navigate in the Agenda buffer with `f` (`org-agenda-later`) and `b` (`org-agenda-earlier`), the view goes back to show searches related to `A`. If someone has an idea of how to prevent that, I'm interested.